# What should I do about a board that sparks when I connect my PC but not other devices?

Tags: electrical, repair

I have a board, which has three switches. When I connect my PC's power card to that board, I see a spark in the switch. However, if I connect a TV or a radio, I don't see any sparking.

Do I have to replace that switch? The entire board? Do I have to check the power supply of my home? I suspect that this problem may be occurring due to voltage variation.

Comment: It's not clear from your question what you mean by "board"? I'm guessing maybe a "power bar"? A picture might help, as well as what country you're in (which will tell us what voltage, type of plugs, etc).

Comment: @gregmac: looks like the OP is in India, which has 230V @ 50Hz

Comment: Just found this resource for voltage, frequency and plug type: http://www.kropla.com/electric2.htm

Comment: if this turns out to be a computer problem this question would be better suited for Superuser

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the PC's PSU is either on, or draws considerable power even when it's supposed to be "off". I'd be looking at replacing the PSU.